# Read values from string in text file and replace them in final output (awk)

Tags: awk

i want to analyze my log files and send a summary csv file with email but i have problems with my parsing attempts

the log file looks like this:

```
Oct 24 10:39:06 T-FTP-01 internal-sftp[1165]: session opened for local user ftpuser
Oct 24 10:39:06 T-FTP-01 internal-sftp[1165]: opendir "/ftp/user/ftpuser"
Oct 24 10:39:07 T-FTP-01 internal-sftp[1165]: closedir "/ftp/user/ftpuser"
```

i run a awk script to create the csv

```
BEGIN {print "month;day;time;session;output"}
{gsub(/\"/,"",$0)};
{gsub(/\[/,"",$0)};
{print $1 ";" $2 ";" $3 ";" $5 ";" $6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20 }
```

so here is what i want to do:
i want to replace **$5** (which is equivalent to **"internal-sftp[1165]** ) with the name of the user (**$11**)

the session id (in this example 1165) is always in relation to the user column

i already found out, how i can get the informations that i need, but i dont have any idea, how i can put the output in my script, so it can replace everything

```
awk '$7 ~ /opened/ { print $5 " " $11 }' /root/log/sftp.log
```

```
internal-sftp[1165]: ftpuser
internal-sftp[572]: ftpuser
internal-sftp[487]: root
```

Update:
Output above was already filtered with the command above, log looks like

```
Oct 24 10:39:02 T-FTP-01 internal-sftp[1110]: session closed for local user ftpuser
Oct 24 10:39:06 T-FTP-01 internal-sftp[1165]: session opened for local user ftpuser
Oct 24 10:39:06 T-FTP-01 internal-sftp[1165]: opendir "/ftp/user/ftpuser"
Oct 24 10:39:07 T-FTP-01 internal-sftp[1165]: closedir "/ftp/user/ftpuser"
Oct 24 10:40:42 T-FTP-01 internal-sftp[1165]: session closed for local user ftpuser
Oct 24 10:47:01 T-FTP-01 internal-sftp[572]: session opened for local user ftpuser
Oct 24 10:47:01 T-FTP-01 internal-sftp[572]: received client version 6
Oct 24 10:47:01 T-FTP-01 internal-sftp[572]: realpath "/ftp/user/ftpuser"
Oct 24 10:47:01 T-FTP-01 internal-sftp[572]: lstat name "/ftp/user/ftpuser"
Oct 24 10:47:02 T-FTP-01 internal-sftp[572]: opendir "/ftp/user/ftpuser"
Oct 24 10:47:03 T-FTP-01 internal-sftp[572]: closedir "/ftp/user/ftpuser"
Oct 24 10:47:32 T-FTP-01 internal-sftp[572]: opendir "/ftp/user/ftpuser"
Oct 24 10:47:33 T-FTP-01 internal-sftp[572]: closedir "/ftp/user/ftpuser"
Oct 24 10:47:40 T-FTP-01 internal-sftp[572]: open "/ftp/user/ftpuser/test.txt" flags READ mode 0666
Oct 24 10:47:41 T-FTP-01 internal-sftp[572]: close "/ftp/user/ftpuser/test.txt" bytes read 4 written 0
Oct 24 10:49:35 T-FTP-01 internal-sftp[572]: session closed for local user ftpuser
Oct 24 12:53:15 T-FTP-01 internal-sftp[487]: session opened for local user root
```

The problem is, that i can only see the name of the user, when he is logging in, but if he is doing anything else, i can only guess the user by his session id

you can see this if you look in to my first example when the user opens a directory

expected output:

```
Oct 24 10:39:02 ftpuser session closed for local user ftpuser
Oct 24 10:39:06 ftpuser session opened for local user ftpuser
Oct 24 10:39:06 ftpuser opendir "/ftp/user/ftpuser"
Oct 24 10:39:07 ftpuser closedir "/ftp/user/ftpuser"
Oct 24 10:40:42 ftpuser session closed for local user ftpuser
Oct 24 10:47:01 ftpuser session opened for local user ftpuser
Oct 24 10:47:01 ftpuser received client version 6
Oct 24 10:47:01 ftpuser realpath "/ftp/user/ftpuser"
Oct 24 10:47:01 ftpuser lstat name "/ftp/user/ftpuser"
Oct 24 10:47:02 ftpuser opendir "/ftp/user/ftpuser"
Oct 24 10:47:03 ftpuser closedir "/ftp/user/ftpuser"
Oct 24 10:47:32 ftpuser opendir "/ftp/user/ftpuser"
Oct 24 10:47:33 ftpuser closedir "/ftp/user/ftpuser"
Oct 24 10:47:40 ftpuser open "/ftp/user/ftpuser/test.txt" flags READ mode 0666
Oct 24 10:47:41 ftpuser close "/ftp/user/ftpuser/test.txt" bytes read 4 written 0
Oct 24 10:49:35 ftpuser session closed for local user ftpuser
Oct 24 12:53:15 root session opened for local user root
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and **kudos** for sharing your efforts/codes and making it a nice post. Could you please do elaborate how line `internal-sftp[487]: root` is coming in output? As I can't see root in your sample of input. **Also** please do mention sample of output more clearly in text form in your question to make it more clear.

Comment: @NXYBWzyK, In your expected output why there are lines whose 5th field is NOT equal to `internal-sftp[1165]:`? Kindly elaborate more on same.

Comment: the number is a session id, which varies + it depends on the user which is logged in

thats why i want to compare it to the "session opened" line (internal-sftp[1165] -> ftpuser)
the id is random, but it is in relation to the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup: added a few lines to sftp.log:

```
$ tail -3 sftp.log
--------------------
Oct 24 10:47:32 T-FTP-01 EXTERNAL-sftp[666]: session opened for local user NEWUSER
Oct 24 10:47:32 T-FTP-01 internal-sftp[777]: opendir "/ftp/user/ftpuser"
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
$5~/internal-sftp/ { split($5,a,/[][]/)                                  # split 5th field to obtain a[2] == session id
                     if ($0 ~ /session closed for|session opened for/)   # update our map[] array with new session id/username pair?
                         map[a[2]]=$NF
                     if (a[2] in map)                                    # if we have a mapping for this session id then ...
                        $5=map[a[2]]                                     # replace 5th field with username
                   }
1                                                                        # print current line
' sftp.log
```

This generates:

```
Oct 24 10:39:02 T-FTP-01 ftpuser session closed for local user ftpuser
Oct 24 10:39:06 T-FTP-01 ftpuser session opened for local user ftpuser
Oct 24 10:39:06 T-FTP-01 ftpuser opendir "/ftp/user/ftpuser"
Oct 24 10:39:07 T-FTP-01 ftpuser closedir "/ftp/user/ftpuser"
Oct 24 10:40:42 T-FTP-01 ftpuser session closed for local user ftpuser
Oct 24 10:47:01 T-FTP-01 ftpuser session opened for local user ftpuser
Oct 24 10:47:01 T-FTP-01 ftpuser received client version 6
Oct 24 10:47:01 T-FTP-01 ftpuser realpath "/ftp/user/ftpuser"
Oct 24 10:47:01 T-FTP-01 ftpuser lstat name "/ftp/user/ftpuser"
Oct 24 10:47:02 T-FTP-01 ftpuser opendir "/ftp/user/ftpuser"
Oct 24 10:47:03 T-FTP-01 ftpuser closedir "/ftp/user/ftpuser"
Oct 24 10:47:32 T-FTP-01 ftpuser opendir "/ftp/user/ftpuser"
Oct 24 10:47:33 T-FTP-01 ftpuser closedir "/ftp/user/ftpuser"
Oct 24 10:47:40 T-FTP-01 ftpuser open "/ftp/user/ftpuser/test.txt" flags READ mode 0666
Oct 24 10:47:41 T-FTP-01 ftpuser close "/ftp/user/ftpuser/test.txt" bytes read 4 written 0
Oct 24 10:49:35 T-FTP-01 ftpuser session closed for local user ftpuser
Oct 24 12:53:15 T-FTP-01 root session opened for local user root
--------------------
Oct 24 10:47:32 T-FTP-01 EXTERNAL-sftp[666]: session opened for local user NEWUSER
Oct 24 10:47:32 T-FTP-01 internal-sftp[777]: opendir "/ftp/user/ftpuser"
```

**NOTE:** last 2 lines do not replace the 5th field due to a) no match on `$5~/internal-sftp/` or b) no `map[777]` entry

Comment: this works perfect for my test environment, i will try to build it into my script, should work just fine

thanks for your help